# How to make a Unity3d program/plugin and publish it on Asset Store?

Tags: 3d, unity, javascript

I want to make a plugin for Unity3d, like TornadoTwins's FPS Control. How can I do that? I already have Visual Studio 2010 installed.

Comment: Related: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/8516/can-i-write-plugin-extension-to-unity-editor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find documentation for building Unity plug-ins here:

- [Building Plugins for Desktop Platforms](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForDesktop.html)
- [Building Plugins for iOS](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForIOS.html)
- [Building Plugins for Android](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/PluginsForAndroid.html)

Do note that plug-ins only work on the Pro versions only, which I assume means you'll be unable to test the plug-in if you have the free version.

More information about creating content on the Unity asset store can be found [here](http://unity3d.com/asset-store/submit-content).

Comment: I have Pro version.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you are making, it may not have to be a native code plugin. [Here](http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/gui-ExtendingEditor.html) is the documentation for extending the editor.